# Meaning of this table syntax

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
table = table or {}
```

What does this do, why do you put your table in your table?
I‘m thankfull for all kind of help.

Comment: It's useful for table values but not exclusively. It's a Lua idiom based on the behavior of the logical selector operators. Think of it as providing a default value.

Comment: Note that this code does nothing if the standard table library is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code assigns an empty table `{}`to the variable `table` if it is nil, otherwise `table` keeps its original value. Basically it is a shortcut for

```
if table == nil then table = {} end
```

Comment: But what is the point of using this? It is also empty when you do table = {}

Comment: It could be, that the variable already has a non-empty table assigned. The code only assigns {} if table is nil, otherwise it does not touch it. It is a shortcut for `if table == nil then table = {} end`